# How should questions about SPDY be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

This web protocol is becoming more and more popular considering its' value, but it's not in the list of tags.

How should a question be tagged since this tag isn't here?

Answer (score 5):

Since the protocol is used by a browser, I think mentioning the browser would be enough. In the same question it could be mentioned that the OP is trying to do something related to SPDY.

If not, this could extent in a bad way to too many other tags that include WebRTC, HTML5 (File and Audio and Web Storage to name a few), WebGL and anything else that a browser offers (Updated browsers that is) or appears in the future for it.

Comment: Thank-you!  That's a good suggestion.  So we wait until it becomes ubiquitous like AJAX to add the tag?

Comment: This of course would end with the community deciding but AJAX would also fall into the "browser" tag or similar. The thing is, if allowed, this could create many (And I mean MANY) tags that are more related either to other SE sites or used inside another tag like browser.

Comment: No need for an actual SPDY tag in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the context of the question. A lot of servers (i.e. server software) are going to adopt it (SPDY) eventually. I'd go with `webserver` or `server` for now and if you ask about a specific software, such as `nginx`, then add that.

On the client side go with Luis' answer.