# Lets get rid of the localhost tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/localhost) has been on the burner for some time now. Users that know the term, will know that it is the name of the system itself, a network loopback. In the last 30 days, nobody answered any of those questions and nobody seems to continuously use the tag. It should just get removed as it get tagled with questions about apache, networking, ssh, lamp, dns, etc.

Case point where the localhost tag doesn't add anything to the question nor serve to search it more easily.

[Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Comment: Again, you assume [things that are not true](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448944). And what would you say if we will get rid of the [tags](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tags) from meta. For this tag it is a truth the fact that in the last 30 days, nobody accepted an answer any of those questions and nobody (but nobody) follow the tag. Am I correct? If yes, then please consider my advice [from here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8924/when-should-i-use-the-command-line-tag#comment17150_8926).

Comment: localhost seems like a slightly meta tag to me. Do we actually get that many questions *about* localhost? What if we do get a question about localhost? What do we tag it with?

Comment: @Seth exactly my point. "localhost" should be about "networking" most of the time and some times about "apache", some other about "ssh". Is a generic term for multitude of things that already have tag. Is like [spdy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6170/how-should-questions-about-spdy-be-tagged), is a protocol but highly dependent of what you are using.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu "are not true" please, provide evidence that proves me wrong. Otherwise is just an opinion.

Comment: @Braiam Just please click on the link provided in my previous comment. You will be surprised to see a Q with [tag:localhost] tag which was answered to your amazement in the last 30 days.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu but you discovered that question because the localhost tag? The median of users answering and asking questions with localhost tag is 1. That means that is just incidental that they add the tag. That 1 question get answered doesn't mean that the tag was the responsible for it.

Answer (score 8):

[There is already a system in place to get rid of obscure tags that nobody uses](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.

There are already more than 100 questions tagged as [localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/localhost). So, people seem to find its use. If it becomes obsure, the system would take care of removing this tag itself.

There is no need for users to go and find tags that nobody uses and take action to get rid of them.

Comment: The problem is that the [creator of the tag](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7155/where-should-i-place-aliases-for-localhost) was summarizing his question content and his question was about network manager. The [second question asked](http://askubuntu.com/q/17990/169736) is talking about apache and was found 4 days after. Is not an obscured tag, but a tag that **alone in a single question cannot be** since it requires of other tags to makes sense. Can you ask a question about "localhost" where other tags doesn't apply?

Comment: @Braiam The main argument in your question was *"nobody answered any of those questions and nobody seems to continuously use the tag"*, hence my answer was targeted to make you aware that there is already a system in place to take care of not-so-popular tags. As to *"Can you ask a question about "localhost" where other tags doesn't apply?"*, I would let others take over and answer this argument of yours. It should **only** be removed if it's a meta tag aka different people have different ideas about it. As far as I know, localhost doesn't involve confusion about different ideas.

Comment: [People already have different opinions about them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/52IX9.png). And my argument still applies. If you check the [top users](http://askubuntu.com/tags/localhost/topusers) you will notice that the average posts answers/asked with the tag is no over 1. How can you explain that?