# Who are the experts for [localhost]?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Lets get rid of the localhost tag](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8932/lets-get-rid-of-the-localhost-tag) I'm really surprised it met with strong opposition at the time, and I still not convinced, so let me ask if there are really experts in "localhost" question and a question about "localhost" because it seriously escapes my reasoning on "to create a tag there should be experts on the topic".

Comment: There's no place like ::1 !

Comment: @JorgeCastro I don't know how to interpret that.

Comment: @braiam the same as 127.0.0.1, only in IPv6 :-)

Comment: @guntbert I still don't know what he's trying to say. Is he saying that there are experts in "localhost"?

Comment: Aah, you took it serious. I saw it as a joke/famous quote - there are even t-shirts with it.